# MySQL Query too long and spending a lot of time

Tags: php, mysql, time, query-optimization

I'm newbie in stackoverflow. 
My query take to much time (more than 5 minutes).
Can this query become faster?
Please! Help Me! I have no idea :(

I have 2 table Outlet and sales:
1. Outlet : table that have unique data 
     - id_outlet
     - name_outlet
2. Sales : like detail of outlet (1 outlet having much data)
     - id_outlet
     - msisdn (1 outlet having more than 1 msisdn)
     - date

So, I need to get data:
1. Branch
2. Count of Outlet
3. Number of Active Outlet (I get this data from checking existing outlet in this month)
3. Count of msisdn
4. Number of Back Checking Outlet (I get this data from checking existing outlet in this last month but doesn't exist in this month)
5. Number of New Active Outlet (I get this data from checking existing outlet in this month but doesn't exist in last month)
6. Number of Non Active Outlet (I get this data from checking that outlet doesn't exist in last month and this month)
7. Number of Consistant Outlet (I get this data from checking existing outlet in this month and last month)

### **This is my Query:**

```
SELECT branch br, COUNT(DISTINCT id_outlet) AS tot_outlet,
                    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                        FROM outlet o
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 AND branch = br
                        AND id_outlet IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%')) AS aktif,
                    (SELECT COUNT(msisdn) FROM sales s, outlet o
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." and s.date LIKE '".$thisMonth."%' AND o.active=1 AND s.id_outlet = o.id_outlet
                         AND s.branch=br) AS supply,
                    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                        FROM outlet o
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 AND branch = br
                        AND id_outlet IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$lastMonth."%')
                        AND id_outlet NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%')) AS back_checking,
                    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                        FROM outlet o
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 AND branch = br
                        AND id_outlet NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$lastMonth."%')
                        AND id_outlet IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%')) AS new_aktif,
                    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                        FROM outlet o
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 AND branch = br
                        AND id_outlet NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$lastMonth."%')
                        AND id_outlet NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%')) AS non_aktif,
                    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                        FROM outlet o
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 AND branch = br
                        AND id_outlet IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$lastMonth."%')
                        AND id_outlet IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%')) AS konsisten
                FROM outlet o
                WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 
                GROUP BY branch
```

Comment: Start by removing all `LIKE` onthe date field. Use `<= >=` instead. This will be a good starting point.

Comment: Can you take some screenshots, or share the indexes being used on the table?

Comment: Read up on 1. indexing, 2. the `EXPLAIN` command

Comment: @KevinLabécot Removing LIKE shouldn't be necessary in this case, I imagine it is an index issue. This can easily be fixed. LIKE certainly is rather inefficient, but it isn't that bad that it should cause this query to slow to a crawl.

Comment: If I was going there, I wouldn't start from here.

Comment: @Bowebros: I index all field, am I wrong?

Comment: @strawberry : what do you mean?

Comment: MySQL will generally only use a single index on a table in a query.  Hence you will often need indexes that cover multiple columns. A big issue with your query is you have lots of sub queries, each of which contain sub queries used for IN / NOT IN checks. These are not efficient. EXISTS might be faster, or change them to JOINs

Comment: @Kickstart I know that mr. I have try to join that but the results are wrong (sum of outlet isn't same when I sum it manually with ms.excel). and this query have right result, but it's spending too much time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding using the sub queries within the sub queries then you should be able to do something like this:-

```
SELECT branch br, COUNT(DISTINCT id_outlet) AS tot_outlet,
                    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                        FROM outlet o
                        INNER JOIN sales s2 ON o.id_outlet = s2.id_outlet AND s2.DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%'
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." 
                        AND o.active=1 
                        AND o.branch = br) AS aktif,
                    (SELECT COUNT(msisdn) FROM sales s, outlet o
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." 
                        and s.date LIKE '".$thisMonth."%' 
                        AND o.active=1 
                        AND s.id_outlet = o.id_outlet
                         AND s.branch=br) AS supply,
                    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                        FROM outlet o
                        INNER JOIN sales s1 ON o.id_outlet = s1.id_outlet AND s1.DATE LIKE '".$lastMonth."%'
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s2 ON o.id_outlet = s2.id_outlet AND s2.DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%'
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." 
                        AND o.active=1 
                        AND o.branch = br
                        AND s2.id_outlet IS NULL) AS back_checking,
                    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                        FROM outlet o
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s1 ON o.id_outlet = s1.id_outlet AND s1.DATE LIKE '".$lastMonth."%'
                        INNER JOIN sales s2 ON o.id_outlet = s2.id_outlet AND s2.DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%'
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." 
                        AND o.active=1 
                        AND o.branch = br
                        AND s1.id_outlet IS NULL) AS new_aktif,
                    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(o.id_outlet))
                        FROM outlet o
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s1 ON o.id_outlet = s1.id_outlet AND s1.DATE LIKE '".$lastMonth."%'
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s2 ON o.id_outlet = s2.id_outlet AND s2.DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%'
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." 
                        AND o.active=1 
                        AND o.branch = br
                        AND s1.id_outlet IS NULL
                        AND s2.id_outlet IS NULL) AS non_aktif,
                    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(o.id_outlet))
                        FROM outlet o
                        INNER JOIN sales s1 ON o.id_outlet = s1.id_outlet AND s1.DATE LIKE '".$lastMonth."%'
                        INNER JOIN sales s2 ON o.id_outlet = s2.id_outlet AND s2.DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%'
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND o.active=1 AND o.branch = br) AS konsisten
                FROM outlet o
                WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 
                GROUP BY branch
```

This is still using multiple sub queries in the SELECT but depending on the WHERE clause (ie, value of $outlet['status'][$i]) this might not be too bad.

I know you say you have done this but it gave the wrong results, but without example data and table layouts I can't do any checking to figure out how or why this should be wrong.

It might be possible to do this putting the joins in the main query, at least to replace the last 4 sub queries:-

```
SELECT branch br, COUNT(DISTINCT id_outlet) AS tot_outlet,
                    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                        FROM outlet o
                        INNER JOIN sales s2 ON o.id_outlet = s2.id_outlet AND s2.DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%'
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." 
                        AND o.active=1 
                        AND o.branch = br) AS aktif,
                    (SELECT COUNT(msisdn) FROM sales s, outlet o
                        WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." 
                        and s.date LIKE '".$thisMonth."%' 
                        AND o.active=1 
                        AND s.id_outlet = o.id_outlet
                         AND s.branch=br) AS supply,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(s1.id_outlet IS NOT NULL AND s2.id_outlet IS NULL, o.id_outlet, NULL) AS back_checking
                    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(s1.id_outlet IS NULL AND s2.id_outlet IS NOT NULL, o.id_outlet, NULL) AS new_aktif
                    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(s1.id_outlet IS NULL AND s2.id_outlet IS NULL, o.id_outlet, NULL) AS non_aktif
                    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(s1.id_outlet IS NOT NULL AND s2.id_outlet IS NOT NULL, o.id_outlet, NULL) AS konsisten
                FROM outlet o
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s1 ON o.id_outlet = s1.id_outlet AND s1.DATE LIKE '".$lastMonth."%'
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s2 ON o.id_outlet = s2.id_outlet AND s2.DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%'
                WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 
                GROUP BY branch
```

This is relying on COUNT(some expression) only counting non null values.

EDIT.

An option is to change the corelated sub queries into non corelated sub queries, which you do a join against. These are then only each done once, rather than once per returned row. Down side is that joining against a sub query result won't use indexes so the join may not be that fast. Which is more efficient depends on the volume of data.

Taking my earlier query and changing the atkif and supply fields to use non corelated sub queries gives this:-

```
SELECT o.branch br, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT o.id_outlet) AS tot_outlet, 
    COALESCE(sub_aktif.aktif, 0) AS aktif, 
    COALESCE(sub_supply.supply, 0) AS supply, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(s1.id_outlet IS NOT NULL AND s2.id_outlet IS NULL, o.id_outlet, NULL)) AS back_checking,
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(s1.id_outlet IS NULL AND s2.id_outlet IS NOT NULL, o.id_outlet, NULL)) AS new_aktif,
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(s1.id_outlet IS NULL AND s2.id_outlet IS NULL, o.id_outlet, NULL)) AS non_aktif,
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(s1.id_outlet IS NOT NULL AND s2.id_outlet IS NOT NULL, o.id_outlet, NULL)) AS konsisten 
FROM outlet o 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT o.branch, COUNT(DISTINCT(o.id_outlet)) AS aktif
    FROM outlet o 
    INNER JOIN sales s 
    ON o.id_outlet = s.id_outlet 
    WHERE (o.STATUS LIKE 'MALL%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'STREET%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'TOP TEN%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'LIFESTYLE%') 
    AND s.DATE LIKE '2014-10%' AND o.active=1 
    GROUP BY o.branch 
) sub_aktif
ON sub_aktif.branch = o.branch
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT s.branch, COUNT(msisdn) AS supply
    FROM sales s
    INNER JOIN outlet o 
    ON s.id_outlet = o.id_outlet
    WHERE (o.STATUS LIKE 'MALL%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'STREET%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'TOP TEN%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'LIFESTYLE%') 
    AND s.date LIKE '2014-10%' AND o.active=1 
    GROUP BY s.branch 
) sub_supply
ON sub_supply.branch = o.branch
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s1 ON o.id_outlet = s1.id_outlet AND s1.DATE LIKE '2014-09%' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s2 ON o.id_outlet = s2.id_outlet AND s2.DATE LIKE '2014-10%' 
WHERE (o.STATUS LIKE 'MALL%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'STREET%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'TOP TEN%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'LIFESTYLE%') 
AND active=1 
GROUP BY o.branch ;
```

Changing your original query to do this for all the fields gives this:-

```
SELECT o.branch br, COUNT(DISTINCT id_outlet) AS tot_outlet,
    COALESCE(sub_aktif.aktif, 0) AS aktif, 
    COALESCE(sub_supply.supply, 0) AS supply, 
    COALESCE(sub_back_checking.back_checking, 0) AS back_checking, 
    COALESCE(sub_new_aktif.new_aktif, 0) AS new_aktif, 
    COALESCE(sub_non_aktif.non_aktif, 0) AS non_aktif, 
    COALESCE(sub_konsisten.konsisten, 0) AS konsisten
FROM outlet o
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT o.branch, COUNT(DISTINCT(o.id_outlet)) AS aktif
    FROM outlet o 
    INNER JOIN sales s 
    ON o.id_outlet = s.id_outlet 
    WHERE (o.STATUS LIKE 'MALL%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'STREET%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'TOP TEN%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'LIFESTYLE%') 
    AND s.DATE LIKE '2014-10%' AND o.active=1 
    GROUP BY o.branch 
) sub_aktif
ON sub_aktif.branch = o.branch
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT s.branch, COUNT(msisdn) AS supply
    FROM sales s
    INNER JOIN outlet o 
    ON s.id_outlet = o.id_outlet
    WHERE (o.STATUS LIKE 'MALL%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'STREET%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'TOP TEN%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'LIFESTYLE%') 
    AND s.date LIKE '2014-10%' AND o.active=1 
    GROUP BY s.branch 
) sub_supply
ON sub_supply.branch = o.branch
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT o.branch, COUNT(DISTINCT(o.id_outlet)) AS back_checking
    FROM outlet o
    INNER JOIN sales s1
    ON s1.id_outlet = o.id_outlet AND s1.DATE LIKE '2014-09%'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s2
    ON s2.id_outlet = o.id_outlet AND s2.DATE LIKE '2014-10%'
    WHERE (o.STATUS LIKE 'MALL%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'STREET%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'TOP TEN%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'LIFESTYLE%') AND active=1 
    AND s2.id_outlet IS NULL
    GROUP BY o.branch
) sub_back_checking
ON sub_back_checking.branch = o.branch
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT o.branch, COUNT(DISTINCT(o.id_outlet)) AS new_aktif
    FROM outlet o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s1
    ON s1.id_outlet = o.id_outlet AND s1.DATE LIKE '2014-09%'
    INNER JOIN sales s2
    ON s2.id_outlet = o.id_outlet AND s2.DATE LIKE '2014-10%'
    WHERE (o.STATUS LIKE 'MALL%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'STREET%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'TOP TEN%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'LIFESTYLE%') AND active=1 
    AND s1.id_outlet IS NULL
    GROUP BY o.branch
) sub_new_aktif
ON sub_new_aktif.branch = o.branch
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT o.branch, COUNT(DISTINCT(o.id_outlet)) AS non_aktif
    FROM outlet o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s1
    ON s1.id_outlet = o.id_outlet AND s1.DATE LIKE '2014-09%'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s2
    ON s2.id_outlet = o.id_outlet AND s2.DATE LIKE '2014-10%'
    WHERE (o.STATUS LIKE 'MALL%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'STREET%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'TOP TEN%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'LIFESTYLE%') AND active=1 
    AND s1.id_outlet IS NULL
    AND s2.id_outlet IS NULL
    GROUP BY o.branch
) sub_non_aktif
ON sub_non_aktif.branch = o.branch
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT o.branch, COUNT(DISTINCT(o.id_outlet)) AS konsisten
    FROM outlet o
    INNER JOIN sales s1
    ON s1.id_outlet = o.id_outlet AND s1.DATE LIKE '2014-09%'
    INNER JOIN sales s2
    ON s2.id_outlet = o.id_outlet AND s2.DATE LIKE '2014-10%'
    WHERE (o.STATUS LIKE 'MALL%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'STREET%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'TOP TEN%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'LIFESTYLE%') AND active=1 
    GROUP BY o.branch
) sub_konsisten
ON sub_konsisten.branch = o.branch
WHERE (o.STATUS LIKE 'MALL%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'STREET%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'TOP TEN%' OR o.STATUS LIKE 'LIFESTYLE%') AND active=1 
GROUP BY o.branch;
```

The sql fiddle is here:-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1343e/20

Comment: this is my sqlfiddle, please check it sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1343e/1

Comment: after I give index, my query run faster than before (2 minutes). but if put then in my project. its take very long time. :(

Comment: hey @Kickstart . can I get data like this from my tables in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4275/21)

id_outlet | date  a     |  2014-08  a     |  2014-09  a     |  2014-10  b     |  2014-08  b     |  2014-09  b     |  2014-10

Comment: Not quite sure what you want output. Do you want rows as in your SQL fiddle, but with the data from my above queries on each row as well?

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521416/join-one-row-to-all-row-and-returning-all-row)

Answer (score 0):

A few steps to diagnose this yourself.

**Explain your query.**

To explain your query, it is rather simple; you just need to add `EXPLAIN` infront of the `SELECT` part.

Running this;

```
EXPLAIN SELECT branch br, COUNT(DISTINCT id_outlet) AS tot_outlet,
                (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                    FROM outlet o
                    WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 AND branch = br
                    AND id_outlet IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%')) AS aktif,
                (SELECT SUM(featurephone) FROM outlet o
                    WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." 
                    AND active=1 AND branch = br) AS feature,
                (SELECT SUM(smartphone) FROM outlet o
                    WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." 
                    AND active=1 AND branch = br) AS smart,
                (SELECT COUNT(msisdn) FROM sales s, outlet o
                    WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." and s.date LIKE '".$thisMonth."%' AND o.active=1 AND s.id_outlet = o.id_outlet
                     AND s.branch=br) AS supply,
                (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                    FROM outlet o
                    WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 AND branch = br
                    AND id_outlet IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$lastMonth."%')
                    AND id_outlet NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%')) AS back_checking,
                (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                    FROM outlet o
                    WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 AND branch = br
                    AND id_outlet NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$lastMonth."%')
                    AND id_outlet IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%')) AS new_aktif,
                (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                    FROM outlet o
                    WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 AND branch = br
                    AND id_outlet NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$lastMonth."%')
                    AND id_outlet NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%')) AS non_aktif,
                (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_outlet))
                    FROM outlet o
                    WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 AND branch = br
                    AND id_outlet IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$lastMonth."%')
                    AND id_outlet IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_outlet FROM sales WHERE DATE LIKE '".$thisMonth."%')) AS konsisten
            FROM outlet o
            WHERE ".$outlet['status'][$i]." AND active=1 
            GROUP BY branch
```

This will give an output similar to this:

[image: Explain View]

To briefly explain what you should be looking for. THe main thing to look at is the `type`, `possible_keys` and `key`. The main one being `type`.

The value of Type is something that tells you how it is finding the query. The list (in order from best to worst) is: `system, const, eq_ref, ref, fulltext, ref_or_null, unique_subquery, index_subquery, range, index, all`. You DO NOT want any which are all; and most likely, are looking mainly at ref and eq_ref. Yours may have sub queries due to the structure of the query.

To fix this, what I do is look at the structure of the table, and the query. Anything which will benefit from being in a sorted list (which is basically what an index is), gets indexed. For me this means I will index Any foreign key IDs (even if you dont use foreign keys, setup the index); any attributes such as deleted, visible or whatever.

To do it simply, I index most things which get compared in a `where` part of the query. This is a good start; from there, you really should optimize things, because indexes can use ALOT of memory up, but this is a good start for a performance increase.

Comment: this is the picure, I don't get it. what its mean? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9NIhUxYgWVrc0RDcFFmdzRMdTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you see the 'type' column, You have a few with EQ_REF, however the rest are listed as ALL. This is the worst type of thing for a query, because it means that there are no indexes. Do you use Adminer or Phpmyadmin? If so, click on Structure. there, you will see Indexes. Click on Add, and create INDEXES for all of your WHERE conditions. Such as id_outlet (in the outlet table), and branch, active etc. This should speed things up significantly. After each change for an index, run the EXPLAIN query again, and you will see hopefully that the type has changed from ALL to eq_ref.