# join one row to all row and returning all row

Tags: mysql, join

can I get data like this from my [table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4275/22)

```
| id_outlet| date       |  count(msisdn) |  
| 34.10.1  |  2014-08   |      0         |
| 34.10.1  |  2014-09   |      3         |
| 34.10.1  |  2014-10   |      2         |
| 34.10.2  |  2014-08   |      1         |
| 34.10.2  |  2014-09   |      0         |
| 34.10.2  |  2014-10   |      0         |
```

So I have 2 tables
1. table outlet (unique)
2. table sales (detail of table outlet)
As u see in my second table there are 3 periode (2014-08, 2014-09, 2014-10)
I want join that periode with id_outlet in first table like that example.
Can I?
Please Help me

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  I give sample data in my link >> [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4275/22)

Comment: @Barmar thx for edit my question, I'm new here :)

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov : I must adding count(msisdn) like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4275/36). As u see that in table sales there are 3 periode (2014-08, 2014-09, 2014-10), but not all id_outlet having data in table sales. so, I want display id_outlet, periode,count(msisdn). ex: if id_outlet don't have data at periode 2014-08, count(msisdn) should have 0, etc.

Comment: You can edit your question:-) "if id_outlet don't have data at periode 2014-08, count(msisdn) should have 0". But what about sales? Is there 2014-08 or where do you want to retrieve dates from?

Comment: @michaelsivolobov : I already edit my question :) from table sales I just take periode and count(msisdn).  Do u understand?

Comment: If you retrieve `date`s from `sales` and then count `msisdn` you will always have `count > 0`;

Comment: The normal trick in situations like this is that you cross join your list of dates with your list of outlets, so you get every combination of the 2. Then you LEFT OUTER JOIN your actual data against this to get the counts.

Comment: @Kickstart can u give me an example? I don't get it at all T_T

Comment: Added an answer with a sample select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a CROSS JOIN:-

```
SELECT
    o.id_outlet,
    s_main.periode,
    o.branch, 
    count(msisdn)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(date,1,7) AS periode
    FROM sales
) s_main 
CROSS JOIN outlet o
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s
ON s_main.periode = SUBSTRING(s.date,1,7)
AND o.id_outlet = s.id_outlet
WHERE (o.STATUS LIKE 'STREET%')
GROUP BY s_main.periode, o.branch, o.id_outlet
```

If you have a table of dates then you can just use that rather than the sub query to get the dates (which also avoids the potential problem of not having a date in the results for a month where there has been zero sales for any outlet).

Comment: Thats I want. 
Thx So Much @kickstart I'm thinking about it in a day but no answer, and u help me out.

Comment: your query run well in sqlfiddle but if I used my huge data Its spending verry long time. start from time which u take ur answer until now, the result not appear yet :(

Comment: I would suggest adding a table of dates (ie, the months and years you are interested in) and using that instead of the sub query. If possible also add a column to the sales table containing the month / year. At the moment it is having to do a join on a sub query (which won't use indexes) and also on the results of a function (ie, the SUBSTRING) which also will not use an index.

Comment: if I have table of date. I just change this `SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(date,1,7) AS periode
    FROM sales`  right?

Comment: Yes. The sub query will bring back each year / month that exists in Sales, but with a lot of data is probably quite slow. If you replace that with a table of the years / months you are interested in it will just be checking a table with a few dozen records, rather than one with many thousands.

Comment: I don't know. It doesn't work at all in my data. T_T

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my table. i can't add index, i can't do query with simple join. do u have any idea?

Comment: How much data is on the table? Adding an index can take a long time. Any join using a function is not going to use an index and will be slow.

Comment: just 2 million rows. join doesn't use an index? really?

Comment: A join WILL use an index. But if you use an function on the indexed column (such as SUBSTRING) then no index can be used as every value will need the function applied to it before the resulting value can be checked.

Comment: oh IC.. I'll thinking about it.
thx before..
don't be boring if I always asking sumting to u ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, be happy!

```
SELECT
    o.id_outlet,
    SUBSTRING(s.date,1,7) AS periode,
    o.branch 
FROM outlet o LEFT JOIN sales s ON o.id_outlet = s.id_outlet
WHERE (o.STATUS LIKE 'STREET%')
ORDER BY o.id_outlet, YEAR(s.DATE), MONTH(s.DATE), branch
```

Comment: I want to show all id_outlet and all periode  
So, what should I do?

Comment: Say, how to parse 34.10.1 to 1? or Do you want to get that digit, which  after latest dot?

Comment: I want this digit >> 34.10.1 ,  in my question, It just a sample. The point is I want display all id_outlet and periode.

Comment: If I understand you, you must use 'order by', not 'group by'. As 'order BY o.id_outlet, YEAR(s.DATE), MONTH(s.DATE), branch'

Comment: Are u don't understand me? I must explain again. So, I want display 1 id_outlet in table 1 having all date in table 2. (for each id_outlet having all date)

Comment: not that one :( I must adding count(msisdn) like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4275/36) . As u see that in table sales there are 3 periode (2014-08, 2014-09, 2014-10), but not all id_outlet having data in table sales. so, I want display id_outlet, periode,count(msisdn). ex: if id_outlet don't have data at periode 2014-08, count(msisdn) should have 0, etc. thats why in first I used 'group by'. are u get what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need this query:

```
SELECT
    o.id_outlet,
    d.period AS periode,
    o.branch,
    count(msisdn)
FROM dates d LEFT JOIN outlet o ON d.period = SUBSTRING(o.date,1,7) LEFT JOIN sales s ON o.id_outlet = s.id_outlet
WHERE (o.STATUS LIKE 'STREET%')
GROUP BY CONCAT(d.period, '@', s.id_outlet)
ORDER BY o.id_outlet, d.period, branch
```

Comment: have u tried in my [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4275/46) I tried it, but if id_outlet don't have data in table sales, then it not appear :(

Comment: But I want to display `count = 0` too. Can I do that?

Comment: If you want other dates you need a table with these dates. If you retrieve your dates from `sales` and `outlet` you will always have problem that for this date some data already exist. I just swapped `sales` and `outlet`. You can change order it back.

Comment: your fiddle almost done mr. but each id_outlet don't have all periode. :(